# Find controller and method in Typo3 from URL

Tags: typo3

I am new to Typo3. How to find out controller, method and parameters from url in Typo3? I am having following url
URL: localhost/index.php?id=3
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This URL do not contain informations about controller and/or action, just `id` - which is UID o page to display.

If something is displaying there, go to the page and see which plugin is inserted there.

Comment: Thanks Biesior for solution